# How to correctly produce errors from a javac plugin

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to create a `javac` plugin which will do some simple source validation for test classes. Essentially I want to ensure that this piece of code is invalid:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
class Test {
}
```

i.e. The `RunWith` annotation must not contain a `Parameterized` value. I'm able to get to the point of detecting this but I'm unsure how to produce an error correctly; I want the compile to fail with an error. Of course I can throw an exception, but that doesn't seem right.

I'm following the excellent examples from http://www.baeldung.com/java-build-compiler-plugin. My code currently looks like this:

```
public class EnsureCorrectRunsWithPlugin implements Plugin {

  public static final String NAME = "MyPlugin";

  private Context context;

  public String getName() {
    return NAME;
  }

  public void init(JavacTask task, String... args) {
    context = ((BasicJavacTask) task).getContext();
    log("Hello from " + getName());

    task.addTaskListener(new TaskListener() {
      public void started(TaskEvent e) {
        // no-op
      }

      public void finished(TaskEvent e) {
        if (e.getKind() != TaskEvent.Kind.PARSE) {
          return;
        }

        e.getCompilationUnit().accept(new TreeScanner<Void, Void>() {
          @Override
          public Void visitAnnotation(AnnotationTree annotation, Void aVoid) {
            if (annotation.getAnnotationType().toString().equals(RunWith.class.getSimpleName())) {
              log("visiting annotation: " + annotation.getAnnotationType());

              List<? extends ExpressionTree> args = annotation.getArguments();
              for (ExpressionTree arg : args) {
                log("  value: " + arg.toString());

                if (arg.toString().equals(Parameterized.class.getSimpleName())) {
                  // Produce an error here...
                }
              }
            }
            return super.visitAnnotation(annotation, aVoid);
          }

          @Override
          public Void visitClass(ClassTree node, Void aVoid) {
            log("visiting class: " + node);
            return super.visitClass(node, aVoid);
          }
        }, null);
      }
    });
  }

  private void log(String message) {
    Log.instance(context).printRawLines(Log.WriterKind.NOTICE, message);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Trees.printMessage` to output an error message. The first argument controls whether its a warning or an error, and `Kind.Error` will generate an error.

So assuming you stashed `Trees` into a variable `trees`, you can do something like:

`this.trees.printMessage(Kind.Error, "Error from JavaC plugin", tree, compilationUnitTree)`

The third variable, `tree`, indicates the error span.